# PHP status page not working in Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm

Using PHP7.3 FPM along with Apache 2.4.25 I have a problem when enabling PHP FPM status page.

What is working:

```
# /etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
listen = /run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock
pm.status_path = /status-php

# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/status.conf
<VirtualHost [::1]:80 127.0.0.1:80>
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Location /status-php>
                SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

But what does not work is replacing `/status-php` with `/status/php` in both files (PHP and Apache config). This results in 404 and an Apache error saying:

`AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown'`

What is the reason for that? Why is the subfolder-variant not working?

Comment: Is the "php" content identical to the one in "status-php" ?

Comment: Sure, both should return internal status page of PHP-FPM.

Comment: php-fpm requires the SCRIPT_NAME and SCRIPT_FILENAME parameters to correspond to the value of pm.status_path setting. Make sure this is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it my own by replacing

```
<Location /status-php>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</Location>
```

with

```
ProxyPass "/status/php" "unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
```

This way, I can reach PHP-FPM status page via `/status/php` now. No clue why Apache handler fails.